# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away - using curl

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have been working on a sms api, which fetches around 30 records from database and sends sms dynamically using CURL. Each sms has its own unique message and hence this runs in a loop.

My code is here

```
$curl=curl_init('http://smsprovidersite.com/api/sendmsg.php?'.$var);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$response=curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

The code runs and gives the

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away. curl

my my.cnf has max_allowed_packet set to 16M already.

What can be the problem for this?

thank you

Comment: if you use this in a loop you shall put a `sleep()`

Comment: is the sms app yours? Why don't you post the relevent code form that? if it's not yours, there isn't anything you can do expect contact them and tell them about it

Comment: Its a thirdparty sms provider and infact the sms is delivered to the numbers.

Comment: well then there's nothing you can do except to contact them, and this question is effectively off topic

Comment: You mean, even though the SMSs are delivered, its a problem from the SMS providers side?